# Is there a time delay between updates of Google Chrome cookies sqlite database

Tags: java, google-chrome, sqlite

I am working on a Java Desktop app, which checks Google Chrome cookie database `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies` every 2 seconds for a cookie stored by a particular site (say xxxx.com).

The user opens the browser, visits the site *xxxx.com*, which in turn sets a cookie. It takes several seconds before the application shows that the cookie is set.

So, the question is - does Google Chrome has some in-memory cookie management and updates the database after a delay ??

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found the answer to my question [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/cookiemonster) in *Chromium developer section*.

According to it, `SQLitePersistentCookieStore` updates the database every thirty seconds (when it has something to update it about) or if the queue gets too large.
As Google Chrome draws its source code from Chromium (open source), so it's safe to say that it applies to chrome too.